# Wolfram Alpha API JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, wolframalpha

I have recently been working on my J.A.R.V.I.S web app, which I am coding in HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery. I have got the interface, speech recognition, and speech synthesis working so far. I have a few commands already (eg. weather, searching google), but I really want to be able to search Wolfram Alpha for something and use the speech synthesis to say the result, meaning I cannot just open the Wolfram Alpha webpage.

So, I've been trying to figure out how to use the Wolfram Alpha API v2.0. Unfortunately I can't quite figure it out.

Here's what I need:
A method that I can execute with JavaScript/jQuery, which will search Wolfram Alpha for whatever I ask it to, and return the result as plaintext.

Thanks in advance,
Fjpackard.

Comment: You can do this using a system called AsteriskNow which uses PERL and Google Speech API, see http://zaf.github.io/asterisk-speech-recog/

Comment: I will check it out! :)

Comment: Share the project if it is public, sounds cool :)